# На чем писать парсер с авторизацией для сервера?

Tags: javascript, selenium, backend, puppeteer

Я хочу написать парсер для скачки файла с сайта, там нужно проходить авторизацию, я думал использовать puppeteer, но он открывает браузер, что не подходит для сервера, какую библиотеку посоветуйте использовать

Comment: вас смущает открытие окна браузера? `await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, ... })`

Comment: на сервере же нет бразуера, он вроде обязателен

Comment: дефолтное поведение puppeteer - загрузить chrome, который нужен ему для функционирования. для него не имеет значения серверное окружение или какое-то ещё